# How to make only one column editable when the datasource is a SQLContainer

Tags: java, sql, datatable, vaadin

```
    TableQuery tq1 = new TableQuery("employee", connectionPool);
    tq1.setVersionColumn("VERSION");
    employeeContainer = new SQLContainer(tq1);
    employeeTable = new Table();
    employeeTable.setContainerDataSource(employeeContainer);
    employeeTable.setVisibleColumns(new Object[]{
        "firstname", "lastname", "address"});
    employeeTable.setSelectable(true);
    employeeTable.setImmediate(true);
```

In that exmaple im using the SQLContainer-Addon from Vaadin. By using following code, I can set all cells editable.

```
employeeTable.setEditable(true);
```

But i would like to make only one column editable. Lets say address should be the only column which can be edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't really used this to make columns editable, but I guess you could use a custom `ColumnGenerator` to return `TextField`s in an otherwise uneditable table. If you link the TextField's model to the underlying container, you could even have them update each other in both directions. (below code not tested)

```
myTable.addGeneratedColumn("address", new Table.ColumnGenerator() {
    public Component generateCell(Table table, Object itemId, Object columnId) {
        BeanItem<MyBean> item = myContainer.getItem(itemId);
        Property<String> address = item.getItemProperty("address");
        TextField tf = new TextField();
        tf.setPropertyDataSource(address);
        return tf;
    }
}
```

Note: while this may update the container model, I'm not sure that this will effectively commit the changes to the DB, as I'm not familiar with SQLContainer.